# What is the best possible way to make an ui that can scale as the screen size and pd changes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

While running my app the components of it are not being at the place,for which they are designed to be.
I used Constraint layout for designing the front end , i've put lot of time into this and now he components are not being placed at the correct position .
please help me

xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/signup"
tools:context=".signuppage"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">


    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/stuname"
    android:layout_width="256dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Enter Child Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/uname "
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.705"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/uname "
    android:layout_width="256dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Enter Parent Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.705"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/sec"
    android:layout_width="147dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Enter Section"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/uname " />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/Cls"
    android:layout_width="147dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Enter Class"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sec"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/uname " />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/phn"
    android:layout_width="257dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Enter PhoneNumber"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/uname " />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/repass"
    android:layout_width="246dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Re-Enter Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.657"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pass2" />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/pass2"
    android:layout_width="246dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Enter Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.97"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phn" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="152dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/repass"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.336" />
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is signup page when previewed in A.studio it renders properly but when i fire this on a device it fails to render properly

Previewed Image in android studio
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXzae.png)

When fired on device
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9t5M.jpg)

Comment: post the tried xml code, so that it is easy to find out the error!

Comment: Post the input layout and what output your getting and the expected output

Comment: you mean your UI design you create is not properly show which you can design ??

Comment: @MohammadAli my actual intention is my ui components are not properly arranged as they are designed to be when fired on a device.

Comment: can you please give me your background color code @ChiruhasBobbadi

Comment: no problem with the background.

Comment: You have used the constraint layout but the layout you have designed doesn't utilize the features of it properly. You have messed with the parameter horizontal and vertical bias which reflects in the positioning of views. And try using dynamic sizing for views.

Answer (score 0):

Dude your layout file is an absolute mockery.

You are setting a background on constraint layout with all those Edittext background border fixed to the image and you design or you can say arrange your edittext items on top of that image according to the size of what preview you saw on visualizer but hen you fire it on device the dp value change according to screen size.

**The solution**  draw all those background color and border for your edittext seperately.